# Play application compiles perfectly in windows, gives unsupported class version error in mac osx

Tags: java, playframework

I've been developing a Play application on a Windows machine and it works perfectly. I now want to edit it on my Mac laptop. I have play up and running on the Mac and I've copied the files from the windows machine to the Mac. However, when I try to run the application I get the following error:

```
An unexpected error occured caused by exception UnsupportedClassVersionError:
DocViewerPlugin : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I found the solution to this by googling your error. Just saying.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unsupported major.minor version 51.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Mac executes the program with Java 6.  Your program needs Java 7.

For newer Macs Java 7 can be downloaded from Oracle.